# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{3}{x+1} \neq 2 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Prove that $\lim\limits_{x \to 2} \frac{3}{x+1} \neq 2 $

**My Attempt:** Choose $\epsilon = 0.01 > 0$. Then for ant range $|x-2| < \delta \rightarrow -\delta + 2<x<\delta+2$. We know that for any $\delta$ that $f(\delta+2) < 1$ (decreasing function).

$$|f(x)-L| = |f(\delta + 2) -2| > |1-2| = 1 > 0.01$$

Hence contradicting the definition of a limit.

Is this approach valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite.  $a<b$ doesn't necessarily imply that $|a|<|b|$.  Take for instance $a=-4$ and $b=2$.  It's also worth noting that $f$ (assuming that $f(x)=\frac{3}{x+1}$) is only decreasing on $(-\infty, -1)$ and $(-1, \infty)$.  To see this, note that $f(-4)=-1$ and $f(0)=3$, so $a<b$ but $f(a)<f(b)$, so $f$ is not decreasing on the entire space.

Your statement is true if $\delta<3$, so you would need that bound.  (That's okay, because we have control of $\delta$.)

It might be easiest to prove that the $\frac{3}{x+1} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 2$, and use the uniqueness of limits and the fact that $1 \neq 2$ to say that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2} \frac{3}{x+1} \neq 2$.

Comment: This answer deserve an upvote +1